# How do I find the algebra representing the projective bundle of a direct sum of line bundles over a projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry

I am trying to learn how to compute the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(a_1)\oplus \cdots \mathcal{O}(a_k))$ over some projective space using relative proj. How can I find a presentation for the ideal $I$ giving the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m$? For example, I want to understand how I can find an algebra representing the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(1))$ over $\mathbb{P}^1_{s,t}$.

---

For my example, I have to twist by $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to get a vanishing $h^1$. Then, there is a map
$$
\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 5} \xrightarrow{ \begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \\ s^2 \\ st \\ t^2 \end{bmatrix}} \mathcal{O}(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(2) \to 0
$$
All that's left is finding the generators of the ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{C}[s,t][x_0,\ldots, x_4]$, which I think has the presentation
$$
(tx_0 - sx_1, x_2x_4 - x_3^2, t^2x_2 - s^2x_4)
$$

Comment: For any locally free sheaf $\mathscr E$, $\mathbb P(\mathscr E)=\mathrm {Proj}\ \mathrm{Sym} (\mathscr E)$. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, I want to get an actual algebra presentation for this construction.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: For example, $\text{Spec}(\text{Sym}(I/I^2))$ for $I = (xy,xz) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,z] = R$ is the scheme $\text{Spec}(R[a,b]/(az-by))$

Comment: But this is projective, so it will not be a Spec and I gave you a presentation as a Proj. I still don't understand what it is that you want. Could you give a projective example?

Comment: Sure, there is a hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(n)) = \text{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[s,t][x,y,z]/(s^ny - t^nz))$ from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122952/on-a-hirzebruch-surface, but I am not sure how to find such an algebra in general.

Comment: Aha, so your question is that you want an absolute Proj and not a relative Proj?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry I did not put that into the question.

Comment: For all of the downvoters, can you please explain why you gave me these votes? It seems like many Hartshorne level questions go above math.stackexchange and are more appropriately written here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I guess I will write it here as it might need more room.

You know that $\mathbb P(\mathscr E)$ remains the same if you twist it by a line bundle. So, choose a sufficiently ample line bundle $\mathscr L$ such that $\mathscr E\otimes \mathscr L$ is generated by global sections and switch $\mathscr E$ with $\mathscr E\otimes \mathscr L$. In other words, you may assume that $\mathscr E$ is generated by global sections.

Now you have a surjective morphism
$$
\mathscr O^{\oplus (m+1)}_X \to \mathscr E.
$$
which using the properties of projective bundles gives you an embedding 
$$
\mathbb P(\mathscr E) \to  X\times \mathbb P^m.
$$

Now, you can probably write down an absolute Proj for $\mathbb P^2\times \mathbb P^m$ and then your original projective bundle is a closed subscheme in there, so you just have to figure out its ideal.

Ta-da.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{E})$ remain the same if I twist by a line bundle?

Comment: No. The sheaf of sections of $\mathbb V(\mathscr E)$ is the dual of $\mathscr E$. This is the same phenomenon as with "standard" $\mathrm{Spec}$ and $\mathrm{Proj}$; $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\simeq \mathrm{Spec} B$ if and only if $A\simeq B$, but the analogous statement fails for  $\mathrm{Proj}$. The twisting with the line bundle corresponds to a $d$-uple type embedding of the projective scheme/bundle. They are abstractly isomorphic, but have a different embedding.

Comment: I created a bounty for a question related to my comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364401/how-can-i-compute-simple-examples-of-the-associated-vector-bundle-to-a-coherent

Comment: Also, why can the Hirzebruch surface have such a simpler presentation, as seen here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122952/on-a-hirzebruch-surface ?