# Can any simplicial toric variety be embedded in a product of projective spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties

In this question - [On a Hirzebruch surface.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122952/on-a-hirzebruch-surface) , the Hirzebruch surface is shown to be isomorphic to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2$.

My question is, does such an isomorphism exist for all toric varieties (or at least simplicial ones)? To be precise, given a toric variety 
$$
(\mathbb{C}^N \backslash U)/(\mathbb{C}^*)^m,
$$ 
can we show that it is isomorphic to a hypersurface of a product of $m$ projective spaces?

At least for complete intersection Calabi-Yaus, this seems to be true, based on https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2875.

Comment: No, such hypersurfaces would have Picard number equal to $m$, but there are many simplicial toric varieties (e.g., weighted projective spaces), which have Picard number 1 (but are not hypersurfaces). In fact, most of the threefolds $P(O+O(a)+O(b))$ (over $P^1$, for $a,b$ integers) cannot be embedded in a product of two projective spaces.

Comment: @byu  In that case, could we instead show that $(\mathbb{C}^N\backslash U/(\mathbb{C^*})^m)$ is isomorphic to a product of $m$ spaces (not necessarily projective) with Picard number 1, or a hypersurface thereof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are well known examples of smooth (hence simplicial) complete toric varieties which are not projective. See for example p. 71 of Fulton's book *Introduction to Toric Varieties*. Any such variety gives a counterexample.

Comment: Which book are you referring to? Introduction to toric varieties?

Comment: That's right. I'll edit to clarify.